# R/dplyr: How do I initialize an empty list of data frames?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a loop that creates several `data frames`.

I want to combine the `data frames` at the end of the `loop` into one big `data frame`. My approach is to store the individual `output data frames` in a list that I can then combine into one `data frame`.

So far, I have initialized a list of length of the number of `files` I will create (`files` is a list of `filenames`):

```
my_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(files))
```

At the end of the loop, the individual `data frames` should be added to my_list but I keep getting this error: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.

I am thinking of using `rbing` or `lapply` but I am not sure how to code them.

Comment: Could you show the line of code that generates the error? If I fill in a specific value, `my_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)` works fine. `lapply` could work too instead of your `for` loop, but we can't really show you how without seeing your `for` loop.

Comment: can you provide a reprex, even if it is with fake data like mtcars and such

Comment: +1 to the requests for a reprex.  The error sounds like there's a problem manipulating the contents of an individual file.  Your idea of binding the list of data.frames together should work.  See, for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62246238/a-set-of-functions-over-multiple-data-frames-and-merge-the-outputs-in-r/62246437#62246437).

Comment: Make sure you are using `[[` to refer to a single list element. `my_list[[1]] <- mtcars` is correct, `my_list[1] <- mtcars` is incorrect, and will give the error that you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass this problem by using a `list` instead of a `vector`, as lists do not have a fixed size.

```r
output_list = list()

for(ii in 1:10){
  # make this iteration df
  df = data.frame(random = runif(10))

# store in list
  output_list[[ii]] = df
}
```

Also works for `c('a','b','c')` instead of `1:10` in the for loop.

Comment: OP is using a `list`. Have a look at `class(vector(mode = "list"))`. The `vector()` method lets you create a list of a certain length. (Though I'm not sure how much pre-allocation helps for lists, when the elements could be any size.)

Comment: Though I do think your example will help, sans the first sentence. My guess is OP is using `[` when they need `[[`.